# Username/Password Azure authentication without ClientID

Tags: c#, azure, azure-identity

Via Azure command line I can login using my personal Entra ID account and generate a MS Graph token using something like this

```
az login -u myusername@mydomain.com -p mypassword --tenant mytenantid
az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph
```

I'm trying to do the same via C# application, but I can't figure out which one of the countless authentication classes I should use.

The easiest one seemed to be the UsernamePasswordCredential, but it has a mandatory clientID parameter that I don't know how to set, since I'm not using any client ID in my az command line.

There would also be an AzureCliCredential class but its options don't seem to include any username nor password parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would always need a client id for logging in (including Azure CLI, PowerShell or Portal).

In case of Azure CLI (which is also an application like any other Azure AD application), the client id is `04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46`.

When you login using `az login -u myusername@mydomain.com -p mypassword --tenant mytenantid`, Azure CLI automatically makes use of above mentioned client id.

[image]

Please see the list of all Microsoft application ids here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/verify-first-party-apps-sign-in#application-ids-of-commonly-used-microsoft-applications.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** that: Azure CLI uses its own ClientID but it is mandatory to pass ClientID if you want to use UsernamePasswordCredential to generate access token.

If you don't want to pass the ClientID while generating the access token, then make use of `DefaultAzureCredential` as a wokkaround like below:

Login with the credentials as below:

```bash
az login -u myusername@mydomain.com -p mypassword --tenant mytenantid
```

[image]

Now **to generate the access token without passing the ClientID**, make use of below code:

```cs
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;

// Define the resource ID for the Azure AD application you want to access.
string resourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

var accessToken = await tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(
    new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new string[] { resourceId + "/.default" })
);

Console.WriteLine(accessToken.Token);
```

***Access token is generated successfully:***

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect. Please see my answer below. Since you are already logged in using `az cli` (which has a pre-defined client id, your code is simply making use of your credentials from there.

Comment: Yes I agree with you CLI has client id using which it makes a call.As per my understanding OP wants to generate access token in c# console without passing the client id. As username password flow requires cient id he doesn't want to implement it.

Comment: In CLI Op is making use of  that command to generate access token without passing client id. But OP wants to do it via c#

Comment: I believe they want to know what client id to use when logging in using C# code.

Comment: "The easiest one seemed to be the UsernamePasswordCredential, but it has a mandatory clientID parameter that I don't know how to set" states the OP doesn't want to pass client ID in UsernamePasswordCredential flow